# Could someone explain this Linux command to me (mount plus options)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android

I found an Android(Linux) command:

> mount -oremount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

Could someone explain me what this means?

Comment: looks like someone is trying to understand jailbreaking their droid

Comment: yeah, I am trying to remove the stock apps ....

Comment: If you want to play with your phone, start here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/ but 'at your own risk'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mount (make available) the device /dev/block/mtdblock3 at the mount point (folder) /system, using the -o (optional) commands to make the device read-writeable and remount it if it's already mounted.

Comment: Hi, your explain is good, but can you explain the parameters :/dev/block/mtdblock3 and -oremount,rw ? Or some references are appreciated, thanks !

Comment: /dev/block/mtdblock3 is the name given to the storage device (flash memory or storage card) in your phone by the phones Operating System. -o says 'here comes some options for the command' and those options (separated by commas) are 'remount' and 'rw' - have a look here: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_mount.htm

Answer (score 3):

It remounts the given filesystem as read/write on the given mountpoint. It's usually used because the filesystem was previously mounted read-only and write access is now needed.

Comment: what is this parameter : "-oremount" ? and this /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system mean ?   I know what they do know, but I don't understand the command.

Comment: `-o` passes options to `mount`. http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: but why -o cascade with remount without any space ? I was thinking that they are a paramaeter?

Comment: it might work with a space....it just has to do with how mount processes the options.  on a pure linux box it works with a space, don't know about the droid platform.  if a command line utility takes multi-letter options with a single - then this would fail.  it's peculiar to mount